# Using destroy() with some parameter other than pk

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

TLDR --> Is it possible to `destroy()` an item in DB using some parameter instead of pk?

I am using ViewSet in my DRF application. I am interested in `destroy()`-ing some queryset items. I would like to avoid using `pk`, can I do that? My approximate model/approach is as following.

```
class MyAwesomeMode(models.Model):
  awesome_field = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
  # some other fields
```

Now, my intention is to `destroy()` the Queryset element without using `pk` and using `awesome_field`. What do I need to do with my ViewSet?

Comment: I don't even know where does `destroy()` function come from. Please add more context to your question.

Comment: @ShangWang _I am using ViewSet in my DRF application_

Comment: What ViewSet are you using in this view?

Comment: Feel free to refer to [ViewSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets) for details. `destroy()` is a method provided by the [framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org) to DELETE a DB entry which can be identified by a unique URL.

Comment: `viewsets.ViewSet` and adding to it `list()`, `retrieve()` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance you all. I seem to have found the cure to my method's ailment. I'd be happy to write my solution (on-demand) in case someone else encounters similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use [ViewSet](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/viewsets.py#L120) and that class extends from `ViewSetMixin` and `views.APIView`, the `.destroy()` method is not available.

You need extend from [`DestroyModelMixin`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L81) to use the [`.destroy()`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L85) method.

About your question, first take a look to the `.destroy()` source code:

```
def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = self.get_object()  # Here is getting the object!
    self.perform_destroy(instance)
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

So, let's say you give a `unique_name` param in your request, you could override the `.get_object()` method:

```
class MyView(ViewSet, DestroyModelMixin):

    def get_object(self):
        return MyModel.objects.get(unique_name=request.data.get('unique_name'))
```

Then, when `.destroy()` calls `self.get_object()` will use your method, where you got the object based on the imaginary `unique_name` field istead of `pk`.

Comment: You are making it unnecessarily complex. The solution which worked on my end is simple. I added `lookup_field = "my_awesome_field"` and changed my method to `destroy(self , request , my_awesome_field = None)` and did my queryset filtering and deletion inside `destroy()`.

Comment: @MuhammadFahadManzoor My solution is only rewrite the `get_object`, other code is an explanation. You solution works for this case, it is a specific solution, my solution could work for many other class using `get_object` in a super class. I am glad you found a solution.